# Starting Node.js scripts on Rasbian

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

Normally i use nodejs on windows. 
But now i clone my nodejs app on raspberry pi and problems starts.

App works when:

```
>> cd /home/dietpi/programs/esp32-node-server && npm start
```

And not working:

```
>> sudo node /home/dietpi/programs/esp32-node-server/index.js
```

Error:

```
/home/dietpi/programs/my-project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:579
    throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
    ^
Error [MongooseError]: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at new MongooseError (/home/dietpi/programs/esp32-node-server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/mongooseError.js:10:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/dietpi/programs/esp32-node-server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:579:11)
    at Mongoose.connect (/home/dietpi/programs/esp32-node-server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:333:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dietpi/programs/esp32-node-server/app.js:17:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dietpi/programs/esp32-node-server/index.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  message: 'The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.',
  name: 'MongooseError'
}
```

App have following package.json:

```
"name": "esp32-node",
"version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "watch": "nodemon index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "JK",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.11",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^2.0.3",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.0.0"
  }
}
```

What causes this? Some basic linux permission stuff? Or what?

Comment: Share your Mongoose connection code. I have had this issue before.

Comment: I think problem is  "linux properties". Because everything works on Windows and on linux  if i "cd" in project folder and run "npm start". But now i try make rasbian autostart with systemd and found this mystery problem..

Comment: No, sometimes the libraries execute a little differently on each OS. Show me the how you connect to your MongoDB. Censor out any sensitive stuff.

Comment: ok. I post mongoDB code later today. Maybe that "root path" way to execute script missed ".env" file. ".env" file contains "MONGO_URI".

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
I try run my nodejs app with "node", but correct way is run it with "npm".

Working autostart systemd service script is:

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/dietpi/programs/esp32-node-server
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/npm start
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=esp32-node-server
User=root
Group=root
Environment=NODE_ENV=production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```